# Существует ли способ создания экземпляров класса по ходу программы?

Tags: python, классы

Предположим, есть класс DrawRectangle. Нужно походу программы создавать экземпляры это класса и обновлять его. Также, требуется полный доступ к этому экземпляру. Возможно ли такое?

```
class DrawRectangle():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def update(self, NewB):
        module.draw.rect(x, y)
AB = B(10, 20)
BC = A(20, 10)
AB.update()
AC.update()
```

Comment: Конечно. А разве AB = B(10, 20) -  это не создание экземпляра класса?

Comment: создать экземпляр: `ab = DrawRectangle(10,20)` , методу `update` при вызове надо передать параметр (`NewB`), ну и функция `module.draw.rect()` должна быть определена в коде